# Chocolatey List for Updated packages only without a version?

Tags: chocolatey

I am currently using this reference that I found on another "Stack Overflow" post:
`choco list -l -r --id-only | ForEach-Object {echo "choco install -y $PSItem"}`

Can someone tell me if is possible to do the same thing but only with updated packages vs all of the packages?
Thanks.

Tried this, but only returned "chocolatey"
choco list outdated -l -r --id-only | ForEach-Object {echo "choco install -y $PSItem"}

Comment: Can you provide some more information about exactly what it is that you are trying to do? You mention doing an `install` but only for packages that are outdated.  Why would you be installing a package? Wouldn't you be upgrading it?  Is there a reason that `choco upgrade all` doesn't do what you want/need?

Comment: I am trying to build a script that will download the outdated packages to our Internal repository.  I was using this as a baseline that I can modify from.  If there is another way, I am open to hearing it.

Comment: There are some example scripts on this page: https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/guides/organizations/automate-package-internalization#script-get-updatedpackage.ps1 which show how you can automate the internalization of packages to an internal repository from the Chocolatey Community Repository using Jenkins as the engine.  Perhaps you can find some useful examples in there.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible  use the **choco outdated** command

```
choco outdated -r --id-only | ForEach-Object { echo "choco install -y $_" }
```

Comment: Thanks, but still leaves the Version and False attached:

Comment: choco install -y chromium|114.0.5735.134|114.0.5735.199|false  
choco install -y dotnet-6.0-desktopruntime|6.0.18|6.0.19|false  
choco install -y GoogleChrome|114.0.5735.134|114.0.5735.199|false